# @InvocableMethod Test Class help

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, invocable-method

I have an @InvocableMethod class that I use with Process Builder, but I am totally stuck on writing a test class for it. I process evaluates a 'Noise' record, and passes the CaseId to the method and promptly deletes it. The Method is:

```
    public with sharing class caseFlagForDelete 
    {
        @InvocableMethod(label='Delete a record')
        public static void CaseDelete(List<Id> CaseIds)
        {
            List<Case> Cases =[SELECT id FROM Case
                              WHERE Case.id IN :CaseIds
                           AND Flag_for_Delete__c = true];
            delete Cases;
       }

}
```

The test I have so far is this, with 0% coverage:

```
@IsTest
public class caseFlagForDeleteTest {
   private static testMethod void runTest()
    {
        Test.startTest();
        list<id> caseIds = getIds(createCases(5));
        //there should be 5 Cases created
        list<case> queriedCases = [select Id from Case];
        system.assertEquals(5, queriedCases.size());

        delete queriedCases;

        //there should be 0 cases...all deleted
        queriedCases = [select Id from Case];
        system.assertEquals(0, queriedCases.size());
        Test.stopTest();    
    }

        public static list<id> getIds (list<sobject> sobjects){
            list<id> output = new list<id>();
            for (sobject SO:sobjects){
                output.add((id)So.get('Id'));
            }
            return output;
    }

        public static list<Case> createCases(integer numberOfCases){
            list<Case> output = new list<Case>();

            for (integer i=0; i<numberOfCases; i++){
            Case a = new Case(Subject = 'Case' + string.valueof(i), Status='New', Origin='Email');
                output.add(a);
        }

        insert output;
        return output;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to actually call the method.

Comment: @Marc - Take the PB completely out of the equation when doing your test. you are not testing the PB you are testing the class. Since PB can change its tough to make a test that relies on it. So as Adrian said, simply execute the method in your test class and assert that the cases that should have been deleted were and that it does not delete those that should not have been

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific way to test @InvocableMethods like web-serivce or rest API. All you need is to call that method directly with correct data setup.

Right now you are assuming that it would run like Trigger or Workflow but, this is not the case. Replace the `delete queriedCases;` with `caseFlagForDelete.CaseDelete(list_of_case_ids);` treating as a `static` method only.

Ex:

```
private static testMethod void runTest()
{
    Test.startTest();
    list<id> caseIds = getIds(createCases(5));
    //there should be 5 Cases created
    list<case> queriedCases = [select Id from Case];
    system.assertEquals(5, queriedCases.size());

    // static method
    caseFlagForDelete.CaseDelete(caseIds); // Invocable method test.

    //there should be 0 cases...all deleted
    queriedCases = [select Id from Case];
    system.assertEquals(0, queriedCases.size());
    Test.stopTest();    
}
```

Comment: May be prudent to also include a test cases where the flag is not set to ensure it was not deleted as a negative test case.