# How to make Test class for an invocable Lead Convert class

Tags: apex, unit-test, visual-workflow

I'm trying to convert a lead by using Apex within Flow. I have this code, that I've found online for doing so. I just can't seem to figure out how to make a test class for it so that I can deploy it to production?

```
    Public class AutoConvertLeads1 
{        
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Convert Leads')
        public static List<String> LeadAssign(List<Requests> requestList) {
        
           List<String> leads = new List<String>();
            
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];    
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();    
         for (Requests req: requestList){             
            Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();    
            Leadconvert.setLeadId(req.LeadId);
            Leadconvert.setAccountId(req.AccountId);                            
            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CleadStatus.MasterLabel);             
            Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); //Remove this line if you want to create an opportunity from Lead Conversion  
            MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);    
        }                  
        if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty())
        {         
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert); 
            for (Database.LeadConvertResult lead: lcr){
                leads.add(lead.getContactId());
            }
            
        } 
            
          return leads;  
    } 
    
      public class Requests {
       @InvocableVariable(label = 'LeadId' required = true)
       public Id LeadId;
       
       @InvocableVariable(label = 'AccountId' required = false)
       public Id AccountId;
    
}
    
   
    
    
}
```

I have a test class put together, but I get the message "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void LeadAssign(List<UnitTest_AutoConvert.Requests>) from the type AutoConvertLeads1". I don't know what the problem is...

```
@isTest
Private class UnitTest_AutoConvert 
{
    Static TestMethod void AutoConvert()
    {
        test.StartTest();
        
        // Create the Lead object
        Lead testLead = new Lead(
            FirstName='Demo 100800',
            LastName = 'Demo 100800 UnitTest',
            Status='Qualified',
            company='Lacosta',
            street='1211 E I-40 Service Rd',
            city=' Oklahoma City',
            state='OK'
        );
        insert  testLead;
        
        List<Requests> newleads = new List<Requests>();
        
        Requests ok = new Requests();
        
        ok.LeadId = testLead.Id;
        ok.AccountId = '0017h00000u4GbTAAU';
        
        newleads.add(ok);
        
        List<object> returns = new List<object>();
        
        AutoConvertLeads1 convert = new AutoConvertLeads1();
        
        convert.LeadAssign(newleads);

        test.stopTest();
        
    }
      
     public class Requests {
       public Id LeadId;
       public Id AccountId;
    
}
   
}
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169895/invocablemethod-test-class-help and see the referenced Q&A above for how to write a test

Comment: avoid the hardcoded accountId in your testmethod

Answer (score 0):

Your specific error is you are redeclaring the Requests class in your unit testmethod

You want this line

```
List<Requests> newleads = new List<Requests>();
```

to be

```
List< AutoConvertLeads1.Requests> newLeads = new List< AutoConvertLeads1.Requests>();
```

remove the declaration of Requests from the testmethod.

**Aside**

Your testmethod has some other issues

1. It doesn't test an input collection of > 1 Requests
2. It uses a hard-coded AccountId which is *not best practice* and can lead to deployment fails
3. It doesn't assert (let alone capture) the return value from the invocable class
4. It doesn't assert anything - like did the invocable do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it with your help. I'm new to Apex, which to your point, is why it was not the best approach.

Comment: That's great to hear; you can mark the answer as accepted as a service to the Community and after you tweak your testmethod, post a new question soliciting advice on how to adhere to best practices. Always good to get started w/ Apex on the right foot - I know I sure wish I had back in 2008.